# Camera not focused when using ARCore with Vuforia?

Tags: unity-game-engine, vuforia

How do I make the camera to be focused since it is always out of focus whenever I use ARCore with vuforia library?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ARCamera control is taken over by ARCore and we have to manually set the camera to be on autofocus mode. Adding this script to camera object worked to be continous autofocus mode.
Script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using Vuforia;

public class CameraFocusController : MonoBehaviour
{
    void Start()
    {
        var vuforia = VuforiaARController.Instance;
        vuforia.RegisterVuforiaStartedCallback(OnVuforiaStarted);
        vuforia.RegisterOnPauseCallback(OnPaused);
    }

    private void OnVuforiaStarted()
    {
        CameraDevice.Instance.SetFocusMode(
            CameraDevice.FocusMode.FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUSAUTO);
    }

    private void OnPaused(bool paused)
    {
        if (!paused) // resumed
        {
            // Set again autofocus mode when app is resumed
            CameraDevice.Instance.SetFocusMode(
               CameraDevice.FocusMode.FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUSAUTO);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is to put this script file? And how to call it?

Comment: you have to add it to your Main Camera gameObject. And these will be called automatically.

Answer (score 0):

This is the new method for the focus

```java
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using Vuforia;

public class CameraFocusController : MonoBehaviour
{
    void Start()
    {
        var vuforia = VuforiaApplication.Instance;
        vuforia.OnVuforiaStarted += OnVuforiaStarted;
        vuforia.OnVuforiaPaused += OnPaused;
    }

    private void OnVuforiaStarted()
    {
        VuforiaBehaviour.Instance.CameraDevice.SetFocusMode(
        Vuforia.FocusMode.FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUSAUTO);
    }

    private void OnPaused(bool paused)
    {
        if (!paused) // resumed
        {
            // Set again autofocus mode when app is resumed
            VuforiaBehaviour.Instance.CameraDevice.SetFocusMode(
            Vuforia.FocusMode.FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUSAUTO);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).